# TYPO3 Mask asks for EXT:example_extension

Tags: typo3, tx-mask, ext-mask

I am new to the TYPO3 Mask extension. I have Typo3 9.5.18 and Mask 4.1.2, both installed via composer.

I have adapted all paths to my site package.

When I select Mask -> Page Template, I get

`(1/2) #1509741912 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
Supplied file object type null for EXT:example_extension/Resources/Public/Images/BackendLayouts/default.gif must be File or FileReference.`

Looks like mask expects an extension `example_extension`. Where can I change this to match my site package?

Answer (score 1):

You can change these settings under `Admin Tools > Settings > Extension Configuration > Mask`.

These settings are stored in your `LocalConfiguration.php` in an array (`EXT > extConf > mask`)

[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMT1b.png)

[Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ued3G.png)

[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Yfh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I had all paths already configured the way you suggested. The real reason was a bit more involved: I had mask installed on a project that already had a few backend layouts. These backend layouts had been generated by the List module and been copied into a *.ts file.

The list module generates the following line in the backend layout:

`icon = EXT:example_extension/Resources/Public/Images/BackendLayouts/default.gif`

As my site package is called `virus`, `example_extension` is not really a match here.

TYPO3 just displays a red icon in this case. Mask seems to be a bit more picky and runs into the described error.

So I'll be careful when migrating a project to mask.